# is it possible to import functions to jenkinsfile outside pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have a simple pipeline.
i was able to take the properties outside the pipeline block and run it successfully.
when i try to move the properties block to either external groovy and import it with "load" or even use shared libraries the pipeline failed.
is there a way to share a block of code outside the pipeline block?

here is my try with shared libraries that failed.

```
@Library("shared-library") _

properties()

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is my try with import groovy that failed.

```
def shared_funcs = load "${env.WORKSPACE}/shared/@script/shared_funcs.groovy"
shared_funcs.properties()

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will output "Required context class hudson.FilePath is missing
Perhaps you forgot to surround the code with a step that provides this, such as: node"

shared_funcs.groovy

```
def call() {
properties([ parameters([
  string( name: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', defaultValue: ''),
  string( name: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', defaultValue: '')
]), pipelineTriggers([]) ])
}
```

Comment: Please show the content of `shared_funcs.groovy`

Comment: i added it to the question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your Global Pipeline Library has the right structure. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure

Make sure you have a file in the vars/ directory of that library. For your purpose it should be named shared_funcs.groovy and be structured as a function.

```
def call(){
  properties([ parameters([
    string( name: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', defaultValue: ''),
    string( name: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY', defaultValue: '')
    ]), pipelineTriggers([]) ])
}
```

You need to have it structured with the `call()` piece for it to work.

Comment: i did. for some reason im facing the error above